# CSS div height 100% layout

Tags: html, css, layout

i am using this code to create the layout of my site. My problem is that "left" and "right" divs does not show on the screen.(They show when i set their height in pixels not in percents) What can i do to show

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>Test</title>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <style type="text/css" media="screen">
    * { 
        margin: 0; 
    }

    html, 
    body { 
        height: 100%; 
    }

    #wrapper {
        min-height: 100%;
        height:     auto !important;
        height:     100%;
        margin:     0 auto -44px; /* -44px being the size of the footer */
    }

    #header { 
        height: 86px; 
    }

    #footer, 
    #push {
        height: 44px;   
    }

    #left
    {
      width:8px;
      width:100%;
      background-color:blue;
      float:left;
    }


    #right
    {
      width:8px;
      width:100%;
      background-color:blue;
      float:right;
    }

    #left: first,
    #right: first,
    {
    content: "";
    height: 0;
    clear: both;
    display: block;
    }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <div id="header">header</div>
        <div id="content">
         <div id="left"></div>
         content
         <div id="right"></div>
        </div>
        <div id="push"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="footer">footer</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your left & right divs have no content at the moment. What are you expecting to see? I suspect they have zero height and so are invisible.

Comment: Check out my answer. @Nick Even though they have no content, it is possible!

Comment: Sorry, what is supposed to show up? `float:left` and `width:100%` are rather contradictiory! Also, `left: first` is an error. Did you mean `left:before` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Working Way:

You need to change these classes:

```
#content {height: 80%;}
#left, #right {width: 30%; height: 100%;}
```

I have updated the code below and posted the complete file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" 
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>Test</title>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <style type="text/css" media="screen">
    * { 
        margin: 0; 
    }

  html, 
  body { 
      height: 100%; 
  }

  #wrapper {
      min-height: 100%;
      height:     100%;
      margin:     0 auto -44px; /* -44px being the size of the footer */
  }

  #header { 
      height: 86px; 
  }

  #footer, 
  #push {
      height: 44px;   
  }

  #left
  {
    width:8px;
    width:30%;
    background-color:blue;
    float:left;
  height: 100%;
  }


  #right
  {
    width:8px;
    width:30%;
    background-color:blue;
    float:right;
  height: 100%;
  }

  #left: first,
  #right: first,
  {
  content: "";
  height: 0;
  clear: both;
  display: block;
  }
  #content {
  height: 80%;
  }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="wrapper">
      <div id="header">header</div>
      <div id="content">
       <div id="left"></div>
       content
       <div id="right"></div>
      </div>
      <div id="push"></div>
  </div>
  <div id="footer">footer</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I get this way:

[image: Layout]

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: hi mat, can you please tell the changes you made in the second solution, i.e: why it is working now? As I previously had the same problem but couldn't figure the way out.

Comment: You solutuin is not what i am trying to achive i want "left" and "right" to have 100% height of the "contetn"( whitch is nto with fixed size ). Your solution makes "left" and "right" go into the footer too.

Comment: Yeah, in that case, you need to divide the layout exactly... So, how do you want, they shouldn't overflow into the footer right, just make the `content`'s height not 100%; Lemme check and let you know.

Comment: Your remark about XHTML doesn't make sense. Your first solution has nothing to do with XHTML, but with the fact that you start triggering quirks mode, which you should never do. Could you delete that part from your answer?

Comment: Because different browsers have different quirks! If you want your HTML page to show up the same in different browsers, you should avoid quirks mode.

Comment: A reset stylesheet won't do any harm, but it doesn't solve all the different quirks between browsers, if that's what you're after. By the way, you have edited your answer, but it still says that it doesn't work with XHTML, just above the solution that does work with XHTML.

Comment: @MrLister Removed that too. :) Thanks for your guidance. :) Being an year working in the front end engineering part, I learnt something new, embarrassing but great. :) Coz till now I have been thinking that using XHTML we cannot use 100% height, and I haven't seen anywhere about that too! :( My bad! :(

Answer (score 0):

After

```
<div id="footer">footer</div>
```

add

```
<br style="clear:both;">
```